# oracle apex interactive grid fetch records from another table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working with Oracle APEX 21.2 and have created two regions on a page:

one is a form region and the other is an Interactive Grid region.

In the form region, I have a Page Item named **TPORDER**_NO and a Button named **GetValue**.

The Interactive Grid region is based on the table Detail_ReadyStock, which has columns `Porder_no, Porder_Date, b_code, p_code, sku_code, ps_code, and box_qty.`

I also have a view called **PendingProdOrder** that contains the same columns as the **Detail_ReadyStock** table: `Porder_no, Porder_Date, b_code, p_code, sku_code, ps_code, and box_qty.` This view stores multiple records.

My requirement is that when I enter a value in the TPORDER_NO Page Item and click the GetValue Button, it fetch all records from View (PendingProdOrder) where Porder_no=PageItem should be displayed in the Interactive Grid region.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Tried many things but not able achieve.

Answer (score 1):

- set interactive grid's "Where clause" property to

  ```
  porder_no = :TPORDER_NO
  ```
- put `TPORDER_NO` into "Page items to submit" interactive grid's property

That's all; when you enter value into `TPORDER_NO` item and push the button, it'll submit the page and cause interactive grid to refresh, using value entered into the page item as a *filter* which will retrieve only rows that satisfy the `where` condition.

Comment: Actual I want to Fetch Records from View into Interactive grid where view.Porder_No = :TPorder_No.

Comment: That's what I already said.

Comment: My question is VIEW is not mentioned , how it will fetch data from VIEW. as per your post it will fetch data from Interactive Grid table with where condition not from VIEW.

Comment: I presumed that you based interactive grid on a view; apparently, you didn't (which is what you actually wrote in question). Well, what's the purpose of that view, then?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Allow me to simplify my question further. I have created a view by combining data from different tables using certain conditions. Now, I want to fetch the records from this view and populate them into an empty Interactive Grid table.

Comment: I see. As interactive grid is based on a table, then you could create a **process** which runs when button is pressed. That process would then "copy" data from view into table so that WHERE clause I mentioned would return rows that satisfy the condition. You'd then be able to modify those values and save them into the table once you're done.

Comment: I created this process `  begin

for c in (
   select Porder_no,Porder_date,B_code,p_code,sku_code,ps_code
    into 
        :Porder_no,:Porder_date,:B_code,:p_code,:sku_code,:ps_code
from 
PendingProdOrder
where POrder_No = :P28_TPORDER_NO)

loop

:PORDER_NO          :=   c.PORDER_NO;
:PORDER_DATE        :=   c.PORDER_DATE;
:B_CODE             :=   c.B_CODE;
:P_CODE             :=   c.P_CODE;
:SKU_CODE           :=   c.SKU_CODE;
:PS_CODE            :=   c.PS_CODE;


end loop;
end;  `            **Server Side Condition ** when button press GetValue

Comment: That won't work, not for interactive grid. It *would* work if you put cursor values into page items, but you aren't.

Comment: could you please guide me ?? how to do

Comment: I've already said everything I meant to, so ... if that doesn't help, I can't assist any further.

Comment: One more thing: if you *background* is Oracle **Forms**, where you'd use a LOOP to populate tabular form, then yes - something like what you posted would do (you're, though, missing NEXT_RECORD; otherwise every new loop round would simply overwrite values from the previous one). But this is not Forms, it is Apex.

Comment: I'm aware that it's Oracle APEX, and I'm currently in the learning process. I have a good understanding of the logic, but I'm exploring how to implement it in Oracle APEX

Answer (score 1):

@Littlefoot has answered correctly, however, that solution requires a page submit. You have not said if you want to submit the form so if you don't want to submit you can achieve this functionality using a dynamic action.

To configure that

- set interactive grid's "Where clause" property to

```
        porder_no = :TPORDER_NO
```

- put `TPORDER_NO` into "Page items to submit" interactive grid's property
- Set the button (GetValue) action to "Defined by Dynamic Action"
- Create a dynamic action on click of button GetValue with a true action of action "Refresh", selection type "Region", Region: your interactive grid.

Comment: Actual I want to Fetch Records from View into Interactive grid where view.Porder_No = :TPorder_No.

Comment: @Kamran I don't understand what you mean. Both Littlefoot and I have given you an answer that explains how to do that. Please be more precise about what exactly it is that doesn't work.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Let me simplify my question. I have a view with multiple records, and I've created an Interactive Grid with an empty table. Now, I want to retrieve the records from the view and populate the Interactive Grid table with them.